# how to only display a value once in a drop down list using php

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I want to pick up information from a database and display it in a drop down list, if the number is in the database more than once I want it only to appear in the drop down list once and then when the user clicks the submit button I want it to appear in a table.

here is my front end code

```html
  <font size="4">font size="4"> Choose an Owner Name</font><br><br> 
<form action="Shaw_R_Q1back2.php" method="post"> 
<select name="HouseID"> 


  <?php

include "connect.php";

  $query = "SELECT distinct `HouseID`,`AskingPrice`,`SoldFor`,`DatePurchased`from purchase order by `HouseID` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid query");  
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{ 
      echo "<option value=\"" . $rows[0] . "\">" . $rows[0] . "</option>"; 
} 

echo "</select>"; 
         

mysqli_close($con); 
?> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit Value">
```

Here is my back end code

```html
<?php

$HouseID = $_POST["HouseID"];
include "connect.php";
$query = "SELECT distinct `HouseID`,`AskingPrice`,`SoldFor`,`DatePurchased`from purchase order by `HouseID` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die($mysqli->connect_error); 

/*$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query"); */
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>House ID</th><th>Asking Price</th></tr>";  
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] .  "</td><td>" .  $row[1] .  "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>"; 
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn); 

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is duplicated? The houseID? If so your database is wrong not the code.

Comment: so is your issue/question that the `HouseID` is not distinct in your select / first code block, or that your are not sure how to use the `$HouseID = $_POST["HouseID"];` in your second code block / query to limit the results?

Comment: no what i want is if the HouseID has two results for say the number 2 then I only want the number 2 to be displayed once in the drop down list and then when the user clicks submit I want both the records to be displayed in a table.

Comment: so if you only want `HouseID`, why is your query - `SELECT distinct \`HouseID\`,\`AskingPrice\`,\`SoldFor\`,\`DatePurchased\` FROM ...` - and not just `SELECT distinct \`HouseID\` FROM ...`. Then in your backend code, you need to remove the `distinct` and add your select `HouseID` - `SELECT distinct \`HouseID\`,\`AskingPrice\`,\`SoldFor\`,\`DatePurchased\` FROM purchase WHERE \`HouseID\` = $_POST["HouseID"]`.

Comment: no I want all the other stuff to display in a table when the user clicks submit

Answer (score 0):

You have things reversed between front end and back end (at least based on my understanding of what you want)
Front end (edited to just the changes needed)

```
$query = "SELECT distinct `HouseID` from purchase order by `HouseID` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid query");  
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
      echo "<option value=\"" . $rows[0] . "\">" . $rows[0] . "</option>"; 
}
```

and back end

```
$query = "SELECT distinct `HouseID`,`AskingPrice`,`SoldFor`,`DatePurchased`from purchase order where HouseID=" . $houseIdPicked;
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>House ID</th><th>Asking Price</th></tr>";  

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr><td>" . $rows[0] .  "</td><td>" .  $rows[1] .  "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: sadly when i tried this code nothing was picked up from the database and the drop down box was blank

Comment: What does the query 
    SELECT distinct HouseID from purchase order by HouseID ASC
itself return when run against the DB?

Comment: it brings up all the houses with there house id, in order starting from 1

Comment: Then using that same query in your php should return the same listing. Keep in mind I only edited the middle section of your code, you still need to include connect etc